# Rails: File to import not found or unreadable: "bootstrap"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am relatively new to programming, therefore I hope that the question is not absolutely stupid.

I got a problem concerning my rails app.

I try to use bootstrap. I built a file called "custom.css.scss" and used the "@import "bootstrap"" line in it.

The problem is: Each time I save my "custom.css.scss" file a new file "custom.css" is automatically generated and I get the following message: "custom.css.scss File to import not found or unreadable:bootstrap".

The funny thing is: When I delete the file "custom.css.scss" and refresh my browser, everything is fine (which means: bootstrap is used).

Do you have any idea, what could be the reason?

Kindest regards
Chris

P.S.: This is my installed gem file

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.1'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'faker', '1.0.1'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.6'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
  # gem 'guard-rspec', '1.2.1'
  # gem 'guard-spork', '1.2.0'  
  # gem 'spork', '0.9.2'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.1.0'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.2.1', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner', '0.7.0'
  gem 'launchy', '2.1.0'
  # gem 'rb-fsevent', '0.9.1', :require => false
  # gem 'growl', '1.0.3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

The custom.css.scss file look like this

```
@import "bootstrap";

/* universal */

html {
    overflow-y:scroll
}

body {
    padding-top: 60px
}

section {
    overflow: auto;
}

textarea {
    resize: vertial;
}

.center {
    text-align: center;
}

.center h1 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* typography */

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    line-height: 1
}

h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.7em;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #999;
}

p {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    line-height: 1.7em;
}
```

Comment: Could you post what `custom.css.scss` looks like where you're doing the import?

Comment: Sure. It looks like this:
@import "bootstrap";

/* universal */

html {
 overflow-y:scroll
}

body {
 padding-top: 60px
}

section {
 overflow: auto;
}

textarea {
 resize: vertial;
}

.center {
 text-align: center;
}

.center h1 {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* typography */

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
 line-height: 1
}

h1 {
 font-size: 3em;
 letter-spacing: -2px;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 text-align: center;
}

h2 {
 font-size: 1.7em;
 letter-spacing: -1px;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #999;
}

p {
 font-size: 1.1em;
 line-height: 1.7em;
}

Comment: Did you: 1) run "bundle install" after editing your Gemfile and 2) restart your rails server?

Comment: Yes, I did both. But it does not work...

Comment: I found out something else, what' very strange. Each time I add a new controller for example with the name "test" rails build up two files in the stylesheets directory: test.css and test.css.scss

Comment: Okay, I think I got it.
I am using the App LiveReload and I ticked the box: "Compile SASS..." - this probably generated the issue!

Thanks for your help!

Regard Chris

Comment: This helped me: https://github.com/anjlab/bootstrap-rails/issues/35#issuecomment-10491002 Thanks,
Jignesh

Answer (score 17):

I had a similar problem and saw Habax's solution and tried the last step first.

**I just restarted the server.**

That turned out to be enough. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue, and I changed the file type from css to scss. I bet if you erase '.css' from your file name it'll work.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue when working on a **Rails 6** application with **Bootstrap 4**.

The issue was that I did not specify the **node modules** full path of the `bootstrap.scss` file in my `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss` file.

After installing **Bootstrap 4** and its dependencies using this command:

```
yarn add bootstrap jquery popper.js
```

All I needed to do was to modify it from:

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

to

```
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

You can then add require the `boostrap.js` file in the `app/javascript/packs/application.js` file this way:

```
require("bootstrap");
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue in a new application, but restarting the development server solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

facing same problem. I rename custom.css.scss to custom.css 
and I specified version of ruby in Gemfile. and bundle install .
in my case:
ruby '2.0.0'

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, solved by fixing bootstrap-sass and sass-rails versions to:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.1.0'
```

And then `bundle install` and server restart.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to past my resolution as a reference. I have also encountered this issue today.
if you also using emacs with scss mode it may be helpful. as default when you save scss file emacs will auto-compile these scss file and create a responding .css file. then you just need to delete these .css file. or put below code to .emacs as permanent fix

```
(setq scss-compile-at-save nil) ;; disable the auto-compilation
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem of "File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap" in my **scss** file. I just solved by adding require statement of **"bootstrap-sass"** to **config.ru** file. My **config.ru** is like the following.

```
# This file is used by Rack-based servers to start the application.

require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
require 'bootstrap-sass' #require statement of bootstrap-sass
run Rails.application
```

Answer (score 0):

Running `npm install` resolved the issue for me.