# Deploy to Heroku Failing on Rails Upgrade from 6.0 to 6.1 - SassC::SyntaxError: Error: File to import not found or unreadable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-6, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I've recently upgraded to latest rails. The upgrade was from 6.0.3.4 to 6.1.3.1.

Everything in development and Production/Heroku worked great prior to the upgrade. Now everything works fine in development (local machine), but fails the `rails assets:precompile` step on Heroku with the following error message:

```
remote: -----> Installing node-v12.16.2-linux-x64
remote: -----> Installing yarn-v1.22.4
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        SassC::SyntaxError: Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.
remote:                on line 21:1 of app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss
remote:        >> @import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

My understanding is that the standard functionality is that it will look in local relative files first, then the node_modules folder.

What is my problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but I needed to add NodeJS buildpack to Heroku in addition to the ruby buildpack. Now Heroku runs the yarn install before building the rails app, which must create the node_modules folder. Consequently, the step that failed during the rails build can now find the bootstrap folder in the node_modules.

The only thing I can think of that I changed was upgrading from Rails 6.0 to 6.1.

Answer (score 0):

probably the file under `node_module` and it was not able to find it

try specifying `@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";`

Comment: Much appreciate your response - but why do you suspect it would have changed?

Comment: Perhaps they removed the method of doing SASS via sprockets/asset pipeline in favor of using Webpack..?

Comment: I do believe so, there is no official place I could find that stats this, but I've seen people report this in quite a few places (and not just 6.1) https://stackoverflow.com/a/63071803/5872935

Comment: I'm currently looking down a different path. Since it works in development, I don't feel that is my best path at this point.

Comment: Mshka, I'm not sure why in the world this would be, but I had to go and explicitly set Heroku to use NodeJS buildpack in addition to ruby buildpack. Now, I did use webpack before upgrading to 6.1 and everything worked find when deploying, so I'm really confused on how Heroku built fine before.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably run test it locally

```
NODE_ENV=production bundle exec rails assets:precompile
```

then run

```
rake assets:precompile
```